# How to move the data completely in to datatable in a single shot, in order to process everything in a disconnected way

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, menu, datatable

I am populating a menu dynamically by storing in database by following code.As of now first i will load parent menu in to a datatable then child menu by using recursion.But the problem is
i am not loading all the menu items in to datatable first rather only parentmenu.This will make perfomance impact.Can anybody modify this code so that it will load every menu items in to datatable
and will do manupulation in a a disconnected way.Or if you a completely different logic, you are welcome for that.

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = this.GetData(0);
            PopulateMenu(dt, 0, null);
        }

 private void PopulateMenu(DataTable dt, int parentMenuId, MenuItem parentMenuItem)
    {
        string currentPage = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem
            {
                Value = row["MENUID"].ToString(),
                Text = row["MENUNAME"].ToString(),
                NavigateUrl = row["URL"].ToString(),
                Selected = row["URL"].ToString().EndsWith(currentPage, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            };
            if (parentMenuId == 0)
            {
                dynamicMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
                DataTable dtChild = this.GetData(int.Parse(menuItem.Value));
                PopulateMenu(dtChild, int.Parse(menuItem.Value), menuItem);
            }
            else
            {
                parentMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(menuItem);
                //dynamicMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
                DataTable dtChild = this.GetData(int.Parse(menuItem.Value));
                PopulateMenu(dtChild, int.Parse(menuItem.Value), menuItem);
            }
        }
    }





    private DataTable GetData(int parentMenuId)
    {
        string query = "SELECT MENUID, MENUNAME, ACTIVE, URL,APPLICATION_ID FROM TESTMNIS WHERE PARENTID = :ParentMenuId  and ACTIVE='Y' ";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserConnections"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query))
            {
                using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":ParentMenuId", parentMenuId);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

database structure is \

```
MENUID  MENUNAME    ACTIVE  PARENTID   ORDERNO   URL  APPLICATION_ID   ROLER_ID    

11  Feedback on System  Y   2   2   ~ASPX/UserFeedBack.aspx Tester  1
3   Reference Data  Y   0   3       Tester  1
26  TAC Y   3   3       Tester  1
27  LAC Y   3   3       Tester  1
```

**EDIT**
Everything working properly with the existing code, the reason behind posting question is performance perspective

**EDIT**

i don't know whether i explained my question properly.This code also will interact with database multiple times.First parent node and then for children.Instead what my plan is take all the nodes in to data table then do the manipulation for parent node and child's from data table

Answer (score 1):

The code below is an example of how to recursively enumerate through your table.  You will have to add the items into the menu properly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("MENUID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("MENUNAME", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ACTIVE", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PARENTID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ORDERNO", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("URL", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("APPLICATION_ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ROLER_ID", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, "Feedback on System", "Y", 2, 2, "~ASPX/UserFeedBack.aspx", "Tester", 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Reference Data", "Y", 0, 3, "Tester", 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 26, "TAC", "Y", 3, 3, "Tester", 1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 27, "LAC", "Y", 3, 3, "Tester", 1 });

            List<DataRow> roots = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable().Where(y => x.Field<int?>("PARENTID") == y.Field<int?>("MENUID")).Count() == 0).ToList();
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            foreach (DataRow row in roots)
            {
                TreeNode node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(string.Join(" , ", row.ItemArray));
                int id = row.Field<int>("MENUID");
                GetChildren(dt, id, node);
            }
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        public void GetChildren(DataTable dt, int parentMenuId, TreeNode node)
        {

            List<DataRow> children = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int?>("PARENTID") == parentMenuId).ToList();
            foreach (DataRow child in children)
            {
                TreeNode newNode = node.Nodes.Add(string.Join(" , ", child.ItemArray));
                int id = child.Field<int>("MENUID"); 
                GetChildren(dt, id, newNode);
            }
        }

    }
}
​
```

Comment: i am getting invalid cast exception for line DataRow main = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("MENUID") == 0).FirstOrDefault();   MENUID i  stored in oracle database as NUMBER datatype but don't know why i am getting

Comment: I added the a first Main Menu Row to your original input data.  Also made the parent of Main Menu a -1 to prevent an endless recursive loop from occurring.  Your error is indicating the column MENUID doesn't contain integers.  It is possible the value is null.  Try changing <int> to <int?> which will allow null to occur.

Comment: it would be good if you can modify your code based on my code. i got stuck somewhere

Comment: I made two basic changes.  First I'm searching the table and getting all the root nodes (ones without parents).  Second I made the project a Windows Form project and putting results into a TreeView.

Comment: again no luck,if you can modify your answer based on my code posted in question ,that would be good

Comment: I don't have your menus so I simulated the best I can with a treeview.  I changed the code to pass the parent id which was easy.  Your code doesn't get all the root nodes, only the one with root = 0.  So I think my improvement to get node 11 is better.  Besides that, my code and your code are the same.

Comment: my code is working perfectly ,my aim is perfomance.Code posted in question is doing recursion by going to database,instead thought of to get all nodes to datatable and then process.In my question 'dynamicMenu' is id of Menu control

Comment: Oh!!! Writen code like this before but all data is usually in the DataTable.  I assume GetData() is getting PARENTID (not MENUID).

Answer (score 0):

Here is code fetching data from database each time assume GetData() is getting parent id.  If you can't get data by parent id then you need to start with each leaf (child with no children) nodes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            DataTable dtRoot = this.GetData(0);

            TreeNode node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(string.Join(" , ",  dtRoot.Rows[0].ItemArray));
            int id = dtRoot.Rows[0].Field<int>("MENUID");
            GetChildren(dt, id, node);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }
        public void GetChildren(DataTable dt, int parentMenuId, TreeNode node)
        {
            DataTable dt = this.GetData(int.Parse(parentMenuId));
            foreach (DataRow child in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                TreeNode newNode = node.Nodes.Add(string.Join(" , ", child.ItemArray));
                int id = child.Field<int>("MENUID"); 
                GetChildren(dt, id, newNode);
            }
        }

    }
}
​
```

Comment: i don't know whether i explained my question properly.This code also will interact with database multiple times.First parent node and then for children.Instead what my plan is take all the nodes in to datatabe then do the manupulation for parent node and childs from datatable

Comment: I've done this lots of times before.  Understand now exactly what you want.  To get the children of Node 0 you need to query the database to find DataRows where the ParentID = 0.  I believe your GetData() method is doing a query on MENUID which will not work.  You need a new query to the database that looks at the ParentID instead of the MENUID.